# あるフィールドにおいて「xx」文字列を含むドキュメントを取り出したい

Tags: firebase, swiftui

#### 前提・実現したいこと

あるフィールドにおいて「xx」文字列を含むドキュメントを取り出したいです。
（例：「山」を入れるとフィールドに「山田」「山本」などが含まれたドキュメントが抽出）
下記のように「山〜」のようなパターンはできているブログは見つけたのですが、
「〜山〜」のようなパターンに対応できる方法は見つかりませんでした。
https://note.com/shogoyamada/n/n8fe9486fcbec

どなたかわかる方がいましたらご教示ください。

#### 該当のソースコード

```
func picker(text: String) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
//このコードだと完全一致でないと抽出できない
    db.collectionGroup("XXX").whereField("title", isEqualTo: text).getDocuments{(snap, error) in
・・・
```

Comment: リンク先の記事はあるフィールドを文字列順に並べた時に、「山」と「山z」(zは実際にはどの文字コードより大きいと判定される文字)の範囲に入るものを全部抽出しているだけです。「〜山〜」と言ったテキストが必ず「ある範囲に入る」並べ方は存在しないので、同じやり方は適用できません。公式サイトでは「Cloud Firestore では、ネイティブ インデックスの作成やドキュメント内のテキスト フィールドの検索をサポートしていません」と明記した上で、「サードパーティの検索サービスを使用」するよう勧める「全文検索」と言う記事がありました。「そのようなことはできない」ことを前提に、アプリの機能や、そう言った「検索サービス」を利用するのか(利用できるのか)など検討しなおされた方が良いように思われます。

Comment: ご回答くださりありがとうございます！
サードパーティの検索サービスを少し試してみようと思います。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。無事にアプリから使えるようなサービスを見つけられた場合には、簡単にでもサービス名やアプリへの組み込み方などを回答として書いていただくと、同じことで悩んでいる方に大変有用な情報となりますので、よろしくお願いします。